# can't run 3D scripts in Processing (Java / openGL-related?)

Tags: java, opengl

I have been running to the same problem in all versions of Processing (visual design software) that I have been using, namely I get a java / openGL-related error, when I try to run 3D scripts. More specifically, I am getting the following message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1652)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:77)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:142)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:128)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2149)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:898)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getGL2ES1(GLProfile.java:789)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL.initSurface(PJOGL.java:250)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.initPrimary(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:6310)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1653)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
```

I have already looked online, but I was not able to find an answer that would give me some solution. I am using a MacBook Pro with OS X 10 (Yosemite) and I am running Processing 2.2.1. Any help would be really welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19229313/2033671)

Answer (score 0):

Austin is right, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838327/458157

OS X 10 still comes with an obsolete version of Java 3D installed by default and it brings an obsolete version of JOGL which is loaded in priority. This old version has no method called javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton(). you can find more information about this concern in my tutorial: http://tinyurl.com/qyf995p