# java jzy3d dependencies issue

Tags: java, jzy3d

I've linked latest jogl library to my project, but unfortunately I have next error during compiling the program `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.isAvailable(Ljava/lang/String;)Z`

what library should I link to solve this issue?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229313/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-media-opengl-gldrawablefactory-initsingleton

Comment: @piyushj, I've already saw it. It didn't help me

Comment: You don't use the correct version of Jzy3D with the correct version of JOGL. The version of Jzy3D you use is obsolete, it looks for GLProfile in the package "javax.media.opengl" which was renamed in JOGL 2.3.1. Please follow "the much cleaner solution" suggested by Rigi at the bottom of his post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19280475/458157 Then, you'll be able to use the latest version of Jzy3D with the latest version of JOGL :) By the way, piyushj is right and you should have read his linked post and the replies more carefully.

Comment: @gouessej, thanks! it helped)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue for myself.

Go here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C2%7Cjogamp

and download gluegen-2.3.2, gluegen-rt-2.3.2, and jogl-all-2.3.2 (or whatever the latest version is). You have to download two things for each, the regular jar AND the source.

Comment: I'm not sure I want manually download anything. The comment under the question already solved the issue.

Comment: Moreover, you need gluegen-rt but not gluegen as Xranby pointed out in another post.