# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V attempting to run worldwind based app

Tags: eclipse-pde

Upgrading a java eclipse program from 32 bit WorldWind libs to 64 and receiving the following error at run time.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V

I'm using jre1.8.0.202
And Worldwind-v2.1.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229313/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-media-opengl-gldrawablefactory-initsingleton)

Comment: After reading  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V I do not belive its a duplicate

Comment: So what happened when you tried creating a Maven dependency?